# How to pass an integer to a query in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, pdo

Edit 1: this is [not about LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152416/how-to-limit-the-paginate-in-cakephp) , this is about passing an integer. Another function that requires passing numbers is [IN](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php)

Edit 2: Should I use PDO::PARAM_INT ?

---

When I do this:

```
$query .=  ' LIMIT ? , ? ';
$values [] =  $offset ;
$values [] = $rows ;
```

At this line:

```
$db->fetchAll ( $query ,   $values);
```

Instead of executing:

```
SELECT .......  LIMIT 0 ,  10;
```

It tries to execute:

```
SELECT .......  LIMIT '0' ,  '10';
```

Causing an error: *Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0' ,'10''*

---

Note 1. I know that there is an option for  [limit in the $params array.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html).

Note 2. There is a question related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835849/cakephp-is-converting-mysql-integers-into-strings-messing-up-rand-function)

Note 3. I have tried: `$values [] = intval($offset)`, `$values [] = (int)$offset`, and even an integer like: `$values [] = 10`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Limit the paginate in cakephp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152416/how-to-limit-the-paginate-in-cakephp)

Comment: @prix, Thanks, but this is not about LIMIT, I just put it there as an example, but I have some query that also require passing integers.

Comment: Though I think you should use prepared statements, if you can find nothing else that works, you could just force `$offset` and `$rows` to int, and then just concatenate them into your query, rather than doing a prepared statement.  Though I don't like this solution much, it should be secure as long as you make sure that $offset and $rows are integers.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno about Cake but in PDO you should use **both**  `intval` and `PDO::PARAM_INT`- none of them would do separately.

In my PDO wrapper I have this issue fixed, allowing first code to run without errors, but I doubt you would bother with implementing it for your framework

Comment: I'll try `PDO::PARAM_INT` later, and let you know if that works.
What is your PDO wrapper ?, can you show it ?

Comment: Don't bother with letting me know - I already know it works :) It's very little wrapper, aimed to solve this very problem by means of extending PDOStatement class  https://github.com/colshrapnel/thebestpdowrapper/blob/master/bestpdo.php - frankly, it does the same things I told you above - it casts to int **and** binds using PARAM_INT, but doing it automatically